# How to create a zoned as/400 DDS definition

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a field from a query which is a calculated total per invoice. I need to create a PF including this field, I wanted to give the type as Zoned but it is not allowing.
I am thinking to use type S. Would that be correct?

```
            Data        Field  Buffer    Buffer
 Field      Type       Length  Length  Position
 VALUE01    ZONED       16  2      16        17
```

as here:     VALUE         12S02

Comment: What kind of query?  What is not allowing it?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: What are you trying to say with `16 2 16 17`?

Comment: 'Not allowing'  What error message?

Comment: A (16, 2) field is probably not going to fit into a (12, 2) space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoned decimal fields are specified with an **S** in position 35 of the field definition.

See the DDS documentation about specifying the [Data type for physical and logical files (position 35)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzakb/ldata.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work:

```
      A            VALUE         12S02
```

You could also create using SQL

```
CREATE TABLE LIBRARY/TABLE01 ( VALUE NUMERIC(12, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 )
```

Anyway, for calculated columns, it is more efficient to use packed (DECIMAL in sql).

Comment: The first line of my answer is in DDS. Sorry, if it is not clear

Comment: Ah, the backtick markdown swallowed the spacing, but on an indented line the spacing you had is more clearly a A-spec. (+1)

Comment: Note that the `0` is optional after `DEFAULT`, since it would be assumed for a number column if not specified.  The default default value, as  it were.